# How to do a IF check within a SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-trigger

I have the following Microsoft SQL Server trigger for my table:

```
-- Insert statements for trigger here
DECLARE @AssignmentUID uniqueidentifier;
DECLARE @ResourceUID uniqueidentifier;
DECLARE @ResourceName nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @ResourceClaimsAccount nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @ProjectUID uniqueidentifier;
DECLARE @ProjectName nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @ProjectUrl nvarchar(1000);
DECLARE @TaskUID uniqueidentifier;
DECLARE @TaskName nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @TaskUrl nvarchar(1000);
DECLARE @UserId nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @PWAUrl nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @sql varchar(8000)

SELECT @AssignmentUID = INSERTED.AssignmentUID 
FROM INSERTED;

SELECT        
    @TaskUID = MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.TaskUID,
    @TaskName = MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskName, 
    @ProjectUID = MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.ProjectUID, 
    @ProjectName = MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectName, 
    @ProjectUrl = MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectWorkspaceInternalHRef, 
    @ResourceUID = MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.ResourceUID, 
    @ResourceClaimsAccount = MSP_EpmResource_UserView.UserClaimsAccount, 
    @ResourceName = MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceName
FROM
    MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    MSP_EpmResource_UserView ON MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.ResourceUID = MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceUID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    MSP_EpmProject_UserView ON MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.ProjectUID = MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    MSP_EpmTask_UserView ON MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.TaskUID = MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskUID
WHERE
    (MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.AssignmentUID = @AssignmentUID);

INSERT INTO tablename
(ItemTitle, ParentName, ParentUrl, Loginname, SourceId, CreatedAt)
VALUES (@TaskName, @ProjectName, @ProjectUrl, RIGHT(@ResourceClaimsAccount, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE('\' + @ResourceClaimsAccount)) - 1), 1, GETDATE());
```

How can i check if @AssignmentUID AND @TaskUID IS NOT NULL before executing the INSERT INTO statement? Is there also potential for optimizing this trigger?

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @AssignmentUID = INSERTED.AssignmentUID FROM INSERTED` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: It is an INSERT trigger. Can this be the case also for an INSERT trigger?

Comment: ***YES!*** Absolutely! ***ALL*** triggers in SQL Server are **once per statement** and deal with possible multiple rows! (e.g. if you insert into a table based on a `SELECT` from another table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write your trigger in a **set-based** fashion to handle the fact that the `Inserted` table might contain multiple rows.

Try this code - it uses your core `SELECT` and does an `INNER JOIN` to the `Inserted` table on that column that you've try to grab in the beginning. This will handle **all** rows that are contained in the `Inserted` table at once - no looping, no cursor - no such messy code needed!

```
INSERT INTO tablename (ItemTitle, ParentName, ParentUrl, Loginname, SourceId, CreatedAt)
SELECT        
    MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskName, 
    MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectName, 
    MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectWorkspaceInternalHRef, 
    RIGHT(MSP_EpmResource_UserView.UserClaimsAccount, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE('\' + MSP_EpmResource_UserView.UserClaimsAccount)) - 1,
    1, 
    SYSDATETIME()
FROM
    MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView 
INNER JOIN
    Inserted i ON MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.AssignmentUID = i.AssignmentUID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    MSP_EpmResource_UserView ON MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.ResourceUID = MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceUID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    MSP_EpmProject_UserView ON MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.ProjectUID = MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    MSP_EpmTask_UserView ON MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.TaskUID = MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskUID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF (@AssignmentUID IS NOT NULL AND @TaskUID IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN 
  ...
END
```